# Django Custom User migrate on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have created a custom User model in Django. Now, I want to run my application on heroku. But I can't run `migrate`, code error:

```
ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations
```

How can I solve this problem?

Full message error

```
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 83, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 223, in build_graph
    self.add_external_dependencies(key, migration)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 188, in add_external_dependencies
    parent = self.check_key(parent, key[0])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 169, in check_key
    raise ValueError("Dependency on app with no migrations: %s" % key[0])
ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: main_site
```

Comment: Is migration file created for that model class?

Comment: Show the full error, not just a snippet of it. What apps is it referring to here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made migrations locally and add "`0001_initial.py`" file to git.

Now it works fine.